# Error in SQL Statement (basic)

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, oracle-sqldeveloper

I'm creating tables for a college excercise, but I keep getting an error executing the query and I can't find the error. SQL Developer is awful specifying it.

This is the SQL Developer output:

```
Error stating in line 58:
CREATE TABLE deportexevento(
  id_evento NUMBER NOT NULL,
  id_deporte NUMBER NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT pk_deportexevento PRIMARY KEY (id_evento, id_deporte),
  CONSTRAINT fk_evento_deportexevento
    FOREIGN KEY (id_evento)
    REFERENCES evento(id),
  CONSTRAINT fk_deporte_deportexevento
    FOREIGN KEY (id_deporte)
    REFERENCES deporte(id)
)

CREATE TABLE evaluador(
  cuil VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL,
  nombre VARCHAR(60) NOT NULL,
  email VARCHAR(60) NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT pk_evaluador PRIMARY KEY (cuil)
)
Error report -
Error SQL: ORA-00922: missing or invalid option
00922. 00000 -  "missing or invalid option"
*Cause:    
*Action:
```

Full SQL: https://pastebin.com/pfCz5Jwt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try a semicolon after each of your create statements, as below...

```
CREATE TABLE deportexevento
(
    id_evento NUMBER NOT NULL,
    id_deporte NUMBER NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT pk_deportexevento PRIMARY KEY ( id_evento, id_deporte ),
    CONSTRAINT fk_evento_deportexevento
        FOREIGN KEY ( id_evento )
        REFERENCES evento( id ),
    CONSTRAINT fk_deporte_deportexevento
        FOREIGN KEY ( id_deporte )
        REFERENCES deporte( id )
);
CREATE TABLE evaluador
(
    cuil VARCHAR( 15 ) NOT NULL,
    nombre VARCHAR( 60 ) NOT NULL,
    email VARCHAR( 60 ) NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT pk_evaluador PRIMARY KEY ( cuil )
);
```

Comment: The output of SQL Developer doesn't print the semicolons, as you can see in the full SQL. Thought of pointing that out in the original post :P

Comment: All of your `CREATE` statements apart from `deportexevento` have semicolons after then in the full SQL.

Comment: Oh my god, though I checked that, so I discarded it. Thanks